# Absolutely cannot get FTP access after adding many rules to iptables in CentOS5

Tags: centos, iptables, vsftpd

I'm just having the worst time trying to get FTP access to the server.   I want to keep the firewall enabled.

**Edit**:  Updated the iptables information.

I have the following rules enabled:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
58398 7869K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 state NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 5841 packets, 350K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4046  299K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   114 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2935  196K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 state NEW
  170 10200 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
   26 10260 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631
 8465  774K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
49907 7084K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpts:30000:35000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:20
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:20 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state ESTABLISHED
```

I know it's waaaay more than necessary, but I'm at my wits end.  I can connect to the server just fine when I disable iptables, so I know it has something to do with the firewall.

I'd just like to connect, using port 21 and a passive connection.  I'd like to open ports 39000 through 40000 for the passive connection.

What do I do?

---

AHA!  I fixed it!  I took another look at the rules and marked down which number rule that reject one was.  I had a hunch it was blocking the rules after it, and it was!

So, it was the following rule that was blocking my connections:

```
49907 7084K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

So what I did to fix it, was restart the server which reset the rules, and then added my port 21 rule to be *before* that reject rule:

```
 sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 11 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 11 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39000:40000 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Then, I added the following to my vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=39000
pasv_min_port=40000
```

Now I can connect, hooray!

Comment: At first glance, you're not allowing port 20, which is ftp-data. However your question does state you want to do a passive connection, which only uses port 21, so this might not be the issue. Just wanted to make sure. Anyway, the second thing is can you use `iptables -nvL` for the output? Just doing `iptables -L` hides a lot of important info.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to get some better info.

Comment: @Patrick I've updated the iptables with the flags that you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer from the question:

---

AHA!  I fixed it!  I took another look at the rules and marked down which number rule that reject one was.  I had a hunch it was blocking the rules after it, and it was!

So, it was the following rule that was blocking my connections:

```
49907 7084K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

So what I did to fix it, was restart the server which reset the rules, and then added my port 21 rule to be *before* that reject rule:

```
 sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 11 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 11 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39000:40000 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Then, I added the following to my vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=40000
pasv_min_port=39000
```

Now I can connect, hooray!